# align env - some symbols are non-italic?

Tags: align, amsmath, italic

I am confused about the behavior of my ams align evironment.
Minimalistic example:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\begin{align*}
\rm{d}x_{\tau} &= R(u) v \rm{d} \tau, \\
\rm{d}v_{\tau} &= - R(u)\nabla U(x)\rm{d}\tau -\gamma v R(u) \rm{d}\tau + \sqrt{\frac{2\gamma R(u)}{\beta}}\rm{d}W_{\tau}
\end{align*}


\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Why are some symbols like "x" or "u" parsed differently, sometimes italic and sometimes not?

Comment: You should not be using `\rm` nowadays, and it does not take arguments. Use `\mathrm{...} `(rm has-been depreciated since 1993)

Comment: @daleif Sorry to chirp in, but it's *deprecated*, not *depreciated* that means a very different thing.

Comment: @egreg was on a new tablet. Predictive text wasn't trained, and I could not spell it anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commands `\rm`, `\it`, `\bf` and similar two-letter font changing commands have been deprecated for almost 30 years. Moreover, they ***didn't*** take arguments, being declarations. The correct syntax 30 years ago (or more) would have been `{\rm d}`. Never use them.

Make yourself a favor and use a different strategy, namely

```
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
```

so you get several advantages, among which

- the spacing is good in (almost) every situation, automatically;
- you can change to an italic “d” whenever you want, just by replacing `\mathrm{d}` with `d`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\diff x_{\tau} &= R(u) v \diff\tau, \\
\diff v_{\tau} &= - R(u)\nabla U(x)\diff\tau -\gamma v R(u) \diff\tau
  + \sqrt{\frac{2\gamma R(u)}{\beta}}\diff W_{\tau}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you briefly explain what the syntax \mathop{}\!\mathrm{d} does?

Comment: @reloh100 It makes an empty operator, so a thin space is added if an ordinary symbol precedes `\diff`, but none for an operation symbol or delimiter. The (empty) operator is followed by an ordinary symbol, so TeX would add a thin space after it, which we remove by `\!`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `fixdif` package, which redefines `\d` macro in math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixdif}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \d x_{\tau} &= R(u) v \d\tau, \\
  \d v_{\tau} &= - R(u)\nabla U(x)\d\tau -\gamma v R(u) \d\tau
    + \sqrt{\frac{2\gamma R(u)}{\beta}}\d W_{\tau}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

If you prefer the italic *d* for the differential operator, just use the `normal` option provided by the package.